# For any $f\in C^1[0,1]$ show that $\sum_{k=1}^n f\big(\frac{k}{n}\big) - n \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ converges to $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

> For any $f\in C^1[0,1]$ show that
> $$ \sum_{k=1}^n f\big(\frac{k}{n}\big) - n \int_0^1 f(x)dx$$ converges to $$\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$ as $n \to \infty$.

I'm completely completely stuck here. Don't know where to start. Some hint would be really appreciated. Can anyone just give me some hints please? I'm not asking for a full solution, just some guidance so that I could do it on my own too.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/914240/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2303994/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472926/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20f%5Cbig(%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cbig)%20-%20n%20%5Cint_0%5E1%20f(x)dx%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much.

Comment: Also recently asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4487454/42969

Comment: @MartinR I didn't know about "approach 0". So is this a search engine for maths solutions here in thus website?

Comment: It is an external math search engine, independent of this site, and (currently) indexes MSE and “Art of Problem Solving.” See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969 for more information. There is also a [dedicated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question)